# Convert PDF file to one JPG or PNG image on centOS

Tags: pdf, centos, jpeg, converters, thumbnails

I need to convert a PDF file to one PNG file. I have tried,

```
convert -thumbnail 400x300 test.pdf test.png
```

This will convert the PDF file to PNG but if the PDF file has multiple pages then multiple image files are created. I want the whole document to be converted to one image file.

Comment: Multiple images in a single PNG file is not supported. Please edit your question and add what you want.

Comment: you might consider using IMageMagick's montage command to put the files for each page together into one image - you'd need to decide how they would be arranged (side by side or top to bottom)